# Additional items for  listview elements

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a listview in my Android application.The content displayed inside each elemnent of this list view is simply a String.But for application logic, each listview item needs to have three Strings(Name,id,rating) associated with it, but only one (Name) needts to be displayed.Therefore, this problem can be summarized as follows.

1- Every listview element consists of three Strings
2- Only one is displayed
3- All Strings should be available when an item is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new object to wrap your data in then use a list of these objects for your array adapter:

```
public class MyObject {

      private final String name;
      private final int id;
      private final int rating;

      public MyObject(String name, int id, int rating){
             this.name = name;
             this.id = id;
             this.rating = rating;
      }

      public String getName(){
          return name;
      }

      public int getId(){
          return id;
      }

      public int getRating(){
          return rating;
      }

}
```

In your Activity create your list:

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject("Name" 123, 5);
MyObject mySecondObject = new MyObject("Name2" 124, 1);

List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>;
list.add(myObject);
list.add(mySecondObject);
```

Pass this list to your array adapter
Once you are in the Adapter you will use getView

Below is roughly what you should be doing:

```
@Override
public void getView(View v, int position){
   // ... something something
   MyObject anObject = (MyObject) list.get(position);

   v.setText(anObject.getName()); // This is the main point

   /// ... something something
   return v;
}
```